# Add migration path to code review?

Tags: feature-request, migration

A lot of questions we see around here are "my code doesn't work" and the OP is just asking someone to look at his code and fix it for them. It might be nice to have an easy migration path for these to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Thoughts?

Comment: are you talking about cases where OP has not made an attempt to have a http://sscce.org/ example, or are you talking about any question that involves code?

Answer (score 5):

Doesn't seem appropriate.

From the FAQ:

> What kind of questions can I ask here?
>
> Code Review - Stack Exchange is for sharing code from projects you are
>   working on for peer review. If you are looking for feedback on a
>   specific working piece of code from your project in the following
>   areas…
>
> ```
> Best practices and design pattern usage
> Security issues
> Performance
> Correctness in unanticipated cases
> ```
>
> then you are in the right place!
>
> However, if your question is not about a particular piece of code and
>   instead is a generally applicable question about …
>
> ```
> Tools, best practices, improving, or conducting code reviews
> Trouble-shooting, debugging, or understanding code snippets
> Higher-level architecture and design of software systems
> ```
>
> then your question is off-topic for this site.

Key things I took from this are:

- "... working piece of code from your project ..." is on topic.
- "Trouble-shooting, debugging, or understanding code snippets" is off topic.

Comment: That all being said, I could see a reason for adding it for actual code review questions but I feel like that doesn't happen very often here.

Comment: In the few cases where it actually makes sense you can just flag for moderator review as we can migrate to any site.  But the general "here's my code what's wrong" questions are off topic for code review.

Comment: I should have read the faq first, I think these questions in general are just unconstructive.

Answer (score 0):

Migrated from comment to Answer

I can see where the questions of "here's my code find whats wrong" can be unconstructive especially if the code is not functional, and the OP has not made an attempt to create an  [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) example.

But I would think that maybe migration to codeReview might not be best, but maybe to programming, or SO.

If the question is maybe about the code not working to the extent of addressing the functionality of a game, or gamedesign principal, so "my character moves like this, but should be moving like this" would be mostly on-topic here (GD), but "my fileIO function isn't outputting, or reading right" would be off-topic, and better suited for an SE that more directly addresses general programming functionality.

I think the big take away isn't so much that all "my code isn't working right" are off-topic, or unconstructive, but instead each should be looked at in isolation as to if the problem with it pertains to Game Development, or if it is a general programming problem/error, and then migrated accordingly if need be.

considering that a good majority of game development (even in most engines) has to do with some level of programming we shouldn't be forcing away questions on helping with programming tuning/functionality, but we should maybe try to at least ask people to have their coding question pertaining to the game development aspect, and not so much the "it just doesn't work" those need to be boiled down to SSCCE, and might need to be migrated to programming, or SO.

[slightTangent]I think users should realize just because your programming for a game doesn't mean that your actual question can only apply to game development. much like most questions about finding a new pathfinding(A*) heuristic can also be about algorithm optimization, or communication between game entities could really be about message queuing between data objects.